# How to control the distances above and below array environment when putting it inside \left| and right|?

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I am trying to write custom commands to allow faster writing of 2 by 2 matrices without having to use `array` each time I need that. The output is good, but since the matrices will be a part of larger table, it is good to minimize the height by removing some of the unwanted vertical space added above and below the contents inside the array.

Also, the result below show very small distance between the matrix itself and the line of the fraction. For someone looking far away, it may look as though there is nothing that separates the matrix from the fraction line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\matTwoByTwo}[4]{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \begin{array}{@{\thinspace}c @{\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace}c@{\thinspace}}
        #1 & #2
        \\
        #3 & #4
    \end{array}
}

\newcommand{\matTwoByTwoAbs}[4]{
\abs{\matTwoByTwo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\matTwoByTwoAbs{a_{4}}{a_{2}}{a_{3}}{a_{1}}}{a_{3}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: beware that macro definitions do not form a group so your `\matTwoByTwoAbs`  command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}`  will stretch all following arrays in the same group, not just the current one.

Comment: If all your matrix elements are simple, like those in your example, you could use `\Bigl| ... \Bigr|` or `\biggl| ... \biggr|` instead of `\left| ... \right|`.  (The latter almost always make the fences too big.)  But you shouldn't just redefine `\abs` with fixed sizes, because that could give a wrong size in other situations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I modified the code as follows  `{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{array}{@{}>{\scriptstyle}c @{\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace}>{\scriptstyle}c@{}}
   #1 & #2
   \\
   #3 & #4
  \end{array}
 }`. @barbara beeton. I do not usually use \Bigl and \Bigr| because they do not dynamically adjust to match the size of their contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are several things in play here, firstly there is the white space within the array itself caused by the strut that is added in each line (so that arrays with capital letters have the same line height as one like this with lowercase, which gives the appearance of space above the array if it is all lower case. Then there is the behaviour of `\left\right` which (within limits set by `\delimtershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` expands to cover the height and depth but *is always vertically centred* so you can not affect the two lengths that you show separately, if you increase the depth of the rules then the height also increases.

I suspect that here it is enough to just add a little more depth to the last row as shown in the second example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\show\arraystretch

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\matTwoByTwo}[4]{{% extra group
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}% this is the default anyway
    \begin{array}{@{\thinspace}c @{\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace}c@{\thinspace}}
        #1 & #2
        \\
        #3 & #4
    \end{array}%
}}

\newcommand{\matTwoByTwoB}[4]{{% extra group
    \begin{array}{@{\thinspace}c @{\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace}c@{\thinspace}}
        #1 & #2
        \\
        #3 & #4\\[2pt]
    \end{array}%
}}
\newcommand{\matTwoByTwoAbs}[4]{%
\abs{\matTwoByTwo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
}
\newcommand{\matTwoByTwoAbsB}[4]{%
\abs{\matTwoByTwoB{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\matTwoByTwoAbs{a_{4}}{a_{2}}{a_{3}}{a_{1}}}{a_{3}}
    \frac{\matTwoByTwoAbsB{a_{4}}{a_{2}}{a_{3}}{a_{1}}}{a_{3}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```